# How change click of a mouse? From the left button to pressing the wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I have a simple link Example:

```
<a href="link.html">Some text</a>
```

How to emulate a click on the link. Change the press of the left button to press the wheel? The options with target are not suitable. Interested in the change is the change of the button for the click.

There is an example code. But it only shows what a click was without changing it.
https://jsfiddle.net/dscshmg4/23/

```
document.getElementById('mouse-click').onmousedown = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 1) {this.innerHTML = "left click"}
    if (e.which == 2) {this.innerHTML = "wheel click"}
    if (e.which == 3) {this.innerHTML = "right click"} 
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. Can you try explain better your goal?

Comment: google translate :( one moment

Answer (score 1):

i think you want change your event , for example if any body press key you trigger right click in mouse

if it is correct , you can use trigger method in jQuery

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

for example

you set key press listener

```
  element.addEventListenr('keyPress' , function () {

      ele.trigger('click');

  });
```

but if you want other thing explain more